# Turning an ASP.NET Website into an AJAX-Enabled one

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have successfully downloaded and installed AJAX framework, and the control toolkit.

While trying to insert any AJAX controls such as UpdatePanels or ScriptManagers into an existent ASP.NET Web Site (which currently has no AJAX functionalities) I get the following error:

"Attempret do read or write protected memory. This is often an indicator that other memory is corrupt."

So as a test, I've created a brand new project, as an ASP.NET AJAX-Enabled Web Site, as follows:

---

[image]

---

And in the default page of this project there is an ScriptManager already, and I've been able to insert an UpdatePanel, do a little test with a label and a button updating its content to the current time.

The question is: What does an "ASP.NET AJAX-Enabled Web Site" have that an "ASP.NET Web Site" does not that prevents me from adding AJAX controls ?

Comment: What .Net version are you using, I think it's built in from 3.5 upwards otherwise you have to install it? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en

Comment: Are you using sourcesafe/sourcegear? Reason I am asking is is that this looks to be one of those edgecase errors and somewhere something went wrong, but I found cases on google that pointed to this :-(

Comment: Use .net 3.5 - there are allot of security policy problems before 3.5. Ajax can be used in jQuery is you want and call a normal aspx page of .net 2.x instead and get params.

Comment: I'm using SVN, but I'm working on this project locally (as a test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more than one version of the AJAX libraries. Often times, the versions can be different between what you have set to use in the configuration file and the controls you are slapping on the page. That is the first place I would check.

You also need to make sure you have the correct version of both AJAX and the control library. This can be you downloaded an old control kit and are using the latest .NET framework, as much of the AJAX functionality has been included in .NET 4.0. Or it can be downloading newer bits and trying to use them with 2.0.

Comment: I might have more than one version installed. Could you help me find out where this conflict is ? How do I remove one version without removing an earlier one ? Before installing the 1.0 (older) version, I've installed a newer one, and that might be it.

Comment: The norm of finding the conflict is checking the references (normally in the web.config file, but can be @Ref tags on a page by page basis) and compare the version number to the version of the control toolkit (can exampine the DLLs in windows explorer for version). If they are not the same, then you need to update references to make thing match. Best bet is make sure you have the latest and only latest installed and then make sure the refs are 4.0.xxx in the references (config and/or page).

Comment: Thank you! I the end I've read thoroughly the working test's web.config to find anything that referenced System.Web.Extensions and AJAX, then copied it into my non-ajax-enabled one, and it has worked. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember (it's been a while since I used AjaxControlToolkit) this error occurs when you attempt to modify the response stream from your code behind (ie: perform a Response.Write(); , or Response.End(); etc etc...

if the method your AsyncPostback trigger is calling is doing any kind of response stream modification then comment it out and try it again as a "proof of concept"..

hopefully this gets you going on the right track.

Dave